# How to use numba.jit with methods

Tags: python, class, jit, numba, function-parameter

Using `numba.jit` in python.

I can convert normal functions to jit-type and run:

```
from numba import jit

def sum(a, b):
    return a+b

func = jit(sum)
print(func(1, 2))
```

How to do this to methods? Something like this (this doesn't work and I know why).

```
from numba import jit

class some_class:
    def __init__(self, something = 0):
        self.number = something
    def get_num(self):
        return self.number

my_object = some_class(5)
func = jit(my_object.get_num)
print(my_object.func())
```

P.S. I've also tried decorators, it works but I can't use it for imported classes (the ones that I don't define myself), so I'm looking into this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot jit **bound** methods, but you can jit unbound methods (but only in object-mode):

```
from numba import jit

class some_class:
    def __init__(self, something = 0):
        self.number = something
    def get_num(self):
        return self.number
    func = jit(get_num)

my_object = some_class(5)
print(my_object.func())
# 5
```

Note that this doesn't use `nopython` mode, so you shouldn't expect any reasonable speed-ups. You could make the class itself a `jitclass` (that means all methods are nopython-jitted automatically) but it requires that you type the attributes:

```
import numba as nb

spec = [
    ('number', nb.int64),
]

@nb.jitclass(spec)
class some_class:
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.number = something
    def get_num(self):
        return self.number

my_object = some_class(5)
print(my_object.get_num())
```

But for more complicated classes it will become very hard (or impossible) to use `jitclass`. In my experience the best way is to simply call the jitted functions from within the method:

```
from numba import njit  # like jit but enforces nopython-mode!

@njit
def my_func(val):
    return val  # this example is a bit stupid, I hope your real code does more!

class some_class:
    def __init__(self, something = 0):
        self.number = something
    def get_num(self):
        return my_func(self.number)

my_object = some_class(5)
print(my_object.get_num())
```

It depends on how complex your class and/or your method is which approach should be used. In your case I wouldn't use numba at all because there's just not enough computationally expensive stuff that would compensate for the numba and jit overhead. If it were a bit more complicated I would use `jitclass` and if it were much more complicated I would use the jitted-function that is called from within the function approach. Personally I would never use `jit` for a method because that implicitly requires object-mode, so it's likely the jitted function is slower than the unjitted function.

By the way: In Python you generally use `property` instead of `get_*` or `set_*` functions...